# Set Zoom Level in WebDriverIO (node js)

Tags: node.js, typescript, webdriver-io

I am working on writing some automation script and it is project's requirement to work with WebDriverIO( node js and typescript). I am stuck in a situation where I have to get some data from web page and I can't use scroll(project requirement) so I want to zoom out(like ctrl+ -). According to WebDriverIO page https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/keys.html I can use there Keys module. But it does not work.

Need some help with it.

For the record I have been using selenium webdriver with c# and there I have done this thing using IJavascriptExecuter. But here I am stuck and couldn't find anything on web related to it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I am working in Visual studio Code IDE and in windows

Comment: Why you can't do it with the same JavaScript executor wdio analog?